# Non-negative, unitary, symmetric matrix is a permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

I have a hypothesis that if a matrix is (**edit**: elementwise) non-negative, unitary and symmetric then it must be a permutation matrix. Does anyone have a proof of this, or otherwise a counter example?

I know that this must be true if the matrix is also traceless, is it also true when it is not traceless?

Comment: By non-negative you mean that every entry should be positive?

Comment: Non-negative usually means that the associated quadratic form $q(v)=\lange v, Av \rangle$ is non-negative.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Not necessarily: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix

Comment: By non-negative I mean that the matrix is elementwise non-negative. Zeros are also allowed. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need symmetry. The assumptions are that $AA'=I$ and $A\ge 0$. For each $i,j,k$ we must have $a_{ik} a_{jk}=0$ whenever $i\ne j$, so for each $k$ only one of the $a_{ik}$'s can be nonzero. Its square must be 1 because of the orthogonality condition, so it equals 1, and then you are done.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Very simple, I'm dissapointed I didn't persist with this more myself.